# How to filter and match query from the URL against pre-defined keywords in an array

Tags: javascript

I need to fetch "q=how to book a bus ticket"(this is the user search) from the URL and look for keywords to match against pre-defined keywords in an array. Also, we need to make sure the keyword is matched exactly against the keyword in the array then active a function. For e.g if the user searches for "I need to buy a new bus" then the function shouldn't be activated coz even tho it has the keyword "bus" in it but it didn't match the exact keyword "bus ticket" in the array.

I have the code to fetch query param from the URL:

```
let params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
let searchedkeyword = params.get("q").toLowerCase();
```

Also, I have a list of keywords in an array:

```
var keyword = [new, book, old car, bus ticket]
```

I tried this one but didn't work:

```
let matchedkeyword = keyword.filter(str => str.match(searchedkeyword));
```

Let me know if this can be done in any other way using JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your match method is wrong, you check if the search query is in the keyword, it should be the opposite, you want to check if the keyword is in the query.
It should be like:

```
searchedkeyword.match(str)
```

Also, match method works with regular expressions and is returning an array with the strings matched, there is no need for that in the filter method, you just need to return true or false, so I suggest using the includes method that does just that.

Here is a code sample using includes:

```js
const searchStr = "I want to buy a bus ticket".toLowerCase();
const keywords = ["new", "book", "buy", "old car", "bus ticket"];

const matchKeywords = keywords.filter(keyword => searchStr.includes(keyword));

console.log(matchKeywords);
```